# Book about a brother and sister that shared a telekinesis connection

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, telekinesis

I’m looking for a book I read in the 80s about a brother and sister that shared a telekinesis connection.

She was able to follow him as he traveled to a different time/realm. She felt the connection when she was petting their dog and could see the current...very weird, I know.

She was in the current time, he was somewhere else and I think it was the location that allowed them to connect via telekinesis. He, I think, was trying to save this other time...

Comment: Are you sure you mean telekinesis (moving things with the power of the mind) or are you referring to a [psychic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic) connection of some description?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum- I remember it was telekinesis as it was the first time I learned about it, but now I’m doubting myself. I remember reading a scene where the sister was petting the dog and she could see the crackling energy that allowed her to go deeper in to the connection with her brother. I have a feeling I will never know this book again. Dim memories of s book that was fascinating to my young mind. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @Maria  I think you mean "telepathy" rather than "telekinesis", by the way it is described.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps "A Swiftly Tilting Planet" by Madeleine L'Engle?

Charles Wallace is traveling in time with a unicorn, named Gaudior, to try to save the world from a mad dictator who is close to starting a nuclear war.  At each point in time where he stops, he gets somehow put into a person in that time, living that person's life but able to somehow influence things. It was called being sent "Within".

His married sister, Meg, follows him telepathically.  They call it "kything".  She does it sitting in her bed with a dog and a kitten, and it works better when she is touching the dog.

Does "St. Patrick's Rune" ring a bell?  Charles Wallace recited it at many points during his journey, usually when in some kind of trouble. It had some power.  I believe he had learned it from Meg's somewhat mad mother-in-law.  It starts, "At Tara in this fateful hour,
I place all Heaven with its power,
And the sun with its brightness,
And the snow with its whiteness,"  Etc.

"At Tara" is sometimes replaced by "With Gaudior"

This is the third book in a series, but each book stands alone also.

The book is available on Open Library https://openlibrary.org/